# How can I display my primary key as a column when using inner join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

```
select StaffNo, SName, BranchName from STAFF  inner join BRANCH on staff.branchno = Branch.branchno;
```

I am trying to display BranchNo in the results from the above query, whenever I add BranchNo after branch name like this.

```
select StaffNo, SName, BranchName, Branchno from STAFF  inner join BRANCH on staff.branchno = Branch.branchno;
```

I get this error code ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined. To my understanding it is something to do with the fact that BranchNo is my primary key, is there a way I can get around this and display BranchNo in the query results? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prefix the ambiguous column name with the table it belongs to.

Actually, you should *always* prefix the columns in multi-table queries with the relevant table names; this makes the queries unambiguous for your database *and* for the readers 
(and future maintainers) of the query.

For this, table aliases come handy (they make the query shorter).

Here is your updated query - I made a few assumptions on from which table each column comes from, that you might need to review:

```
select 
    s.staffno, 
    s.sname, 
    b.branchname,
    s.branchno
from staff s 
inner join branch b on s.branchno = b.branchno;
```